# Do I need to use list() to append a list into another list in Python?

Tags: python, list, append

I am trying to append small (**num**) lists to a final list (**lst**).
The small lists are modified in a loop and at each modification they are appended to the final list.
But the result is strange and I did not like the solution.
Here is the code.

```
n   = 3
num = []
lst = []

for i in range(n) :
    num.append(0)

lst.append(num)

for j in range(n-1) :
    for i in range(n) :
        num[i] += 1
        lst.append(num)

for each in lst :
    print each
```

The result of this code is:

```
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2]
```

However, if instead of using `lst.append(num)`, I use `lst.append(list(num))`, I get the expected result:

```
[0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
```

Is this really the correct way for appending values of a list to another list?

UPDATE:
I see that when I do `lst.append(num)` this does not mean that the values of num are appended to **lst**. It is a reference and because I change the content of **num**, in the end, all entries of my list **lst** will reference to the final **num**. However, if I do this:

```
lst = []

for i in range(3) :
    num = i
    lst.append(num)

for each in lst :
    print each
```

I get what is expected, i.e., a list **lst** with the values [0, 1 , 2]. And in this case, **num** is changed at every iteration and its final value is **num**=2.

Comment: **Hint:** Try `[id(x) for x in lst]`

Comment: If you want to extend (modify-in-place) a list with another list, you can use `a.extend(b)`

Comment: The issue you're seeing is because you're putting a reference to `num` into `lst`, rather than *a copy of num as it looks right now*. When you do `lst.append(list(num))`, you're making a *copy* of `num` and putting that into `lst`, and that copy then doesn't change when you modify `num`.

Comment: Did not you notice the strange thing? For example, at line 8 I append 'num' to 'lst'. At this moment, the list 'num' is [0, 0, 0]. But at the end when I print, this value do not show up in the list 'lst'.
UPDATE: @TomDalton that is what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets have a closer look at this loop.

```
for i in range(n) :
     num[i] += 1
     lst.append(num)
```

You are appending same `num` multiple times. So, all elements of `lst` has the same reference to list `num` and you are updating it at each iteration. That is why you are getting same value at each element of `lst` after the loop has completed.

But, when you are doing `lst.append(list(num))`, you are generating a new list each time. So, each element of `lst` has different reference. And you are getting expected output.

So, to answer your question, the way you are adding a list to a list is fine. That is how you should do it. It has nothing to do with your expected outcome.

Comment: Ok. I understood. Thank you. But I now I have another question on top of that. If I later change completely the value of num and append to the list like:
`
num = 'other thing'
lst.append(num)
`
Then the result is:
`
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2]
other thing
`

Comment: Also see "How do I copy an object in Python?" in the [Programming FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html). list(num) is not the nice way to copy a list.

Comment: @mkiever I see now that is best use num[:] than list(num) to copy the values of num as list to another list

Answer (score 1):

I think the explanation for your result is that when you do `num[i] += 1` you are actually modifying the preceding copies of num that were appended in `lst` at previous stages of the loop. When you do `lst.append(list(num))` you are creating a unique version of `num`.